# How do I annotate my forestplot correctly so that it displays my confidence intervals next to their respective labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, confidence-interval, r-forestplot

I have my data plotted correctly and am happy with how it looks aside from the fact that the confidence intervals are not displayed at all. Here's some dummy code I made up for the sake of my question.

```
library('ggplot2')
blee = rnorm(14)
blarg = rnorm(14)
bloo = (letters[1:14])
low = blee - 1.96 * blarg
up = blee + 1.96 * blarg
knobs = (rep(LETTERS[1:2],7))
df <- data.frame(blee, blarg, bloo, low, up, knobs)

p1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = reorder(bloo, blee), y = blee, ymin = low, ymax = up)) 
        geom_pointrange() + 
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = 2) +
        coord_flip() + 
        xlab('label') + 
        ylab(NULL) + 
        theme_bw() +
        scale_y_discrete(limits = c(-5, 5)) +
        facet_grid(knobs ~ ., scales = 'free', space = 'free')
```

which yields the following:

[image: which yields the following:]

I've tried `p1 + annotate('text', x = bloo, y = 1, label = 'test')` but I yield text for all values, even the ones that do not belong in their respective grid. How do I remedy this? I'm trying to display confidence intervals in text for each individual label.

An image of what is yielded when I try to annotate:

[image: An image of what is yielded when I try to annotate.]

Comment: Can you also add a picture of how your plot currently appears?

Comment: Your sample code renders just fine for me. Only thing I can think of is something going askew with `scale_y_discrete()`. Based on your sample data, `blee` is numeric, so you should use `scale_y_continuous()`. When using `scale_y_continuous()`, if you set your limits too tight, you'll get a warning like `Removed 12 rows containing missing values (geom_pointrange).`. If you simply want to "zoom" in, use `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-5,5))` instead.

Comment: Oh thanks for that! I edited the limit values and now my data works with `scale_y_continuous()`. I'll play around with `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-x,x))` too while I'm at it to see what works.